# Event handling for Sharepoint datagrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm relatively new to SharePoint 2013.  For the past weeks I have been looking through on the web how to handle events in a sharepoint's datagrid view of a list. To be clear, I'm referring to that Excel style view that SharePoint allows you to edit quickly for a list of items.

The question is: how and what should I use to handle an event that fires up when the user goes from one cell to the other.  I want to make some business logic validation or whatever.  Hence, please do not tell me to customise the column and use the default column validation, it works well but in my case I need much more than that...

Hence, I would like you to focus on event-handling of that datagrid (SPgridView?) and to specifically be able to handle events such as:
- on cell focus or leave
- new row added
- row before edit/save/deleted

Also please do not tell me to use Visual Studio to create a web part with a GridControl and deploy it as a SP solution. I'm aware of that too and I don't want for now to go down that route :)

What I think is that there should be some way (JavaScript? but how? what app? SP designer?) how I can handle those events that happen in that Excel-style datagrid.

any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a definite answer to your question but I can point to right direction:

> SharePoint DataSheet Page is used for editing lists in multiple record
>   grid format. DataSheet view uses ListNet control, which is an ActiveX
>   control. This control is also works in conjunction with the
>   ListViewWebPart class to provide users with a dataview for editing
>   lists in Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services.
>
> ListNet control is defined in the STSLIST.DLL file, a dynamic-link
>   library (DLL) that is installed on the client during 2007 Office
>   system setup in the Local_Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Office\OFFICE12 directory.

With the above description, I do not think it is easy to customize this control.

Check out:
http://rajendrashekhawat.blogspot.com/2008/09/custom-datasheet-view-using-listnet.html

Also Check out:

[Extending or modifying the SharePoint Datasheet view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451372/extending-or-modifying-the-sharepoint-datasheet-view)

Comment: Thanks Madhur. I'm not saying it is not an alternative solution but I'm more looking for some solution that I can implement in the SharePoint Designer and handle it javascript wise without writing Vb/C# code. Also it seems that the ListNET is an activeX which from my understanding this has to be deployed through as a Visual studio package...

Comment: Also, a very important point that I want to hit is that I want is to REDUCE development time by maximizin what SP has already built in rather than replicating/mimicking what it has.. you know? I.e. it is better to tweak something rather than re-inventing the wheel for every SpList